# Pass HTTP-NTLM authentication token through script to Exchange

Tags: authentication, iis, passwords, exchange-server, ntlm

I'm developing a web-based system which needs to integrate with several backends, including a Microsoft Exchange server (as well as a few others). The system runs in an air-gapped intranet, so everything is on-prem, no cloud. We've not yet decided whether we're going to develop using Node.js or PHP, but it won't be ASP.NET because we don't have any programmers familiar with it. The intranet has a central Active Directory for all authentication purposes (single forest, no ADFS). Access to the web-based system I'm developing requires Active Directory authentication, which is a simple NTLM over HTTP authentication. So far everything works.

The main issue is that once a user logs-in, I need to pull and process some information from the organizational Exchange server, e.g., the user's calendar. It seems that Exchange has a REST API, but it requires logging-in with the user's password, which I don't have, and everything is supposed to be SSO, i.e., if the user is signed-in to their computer using a domain user they should not be prompted for their password at all.

Is there any way I can get an authentication token from the web server (IIS in my case) and use it for accessing Exchange?

Thank you!

Comment: To configure IIS to use Windows Authentication, you can use the WindowsIdentity class in C# to obtain a security token from IIS. Once you have a security token, you can use it to access Exchange. You can interact with Exchange by using the EWS Managed API, which provides a set of .NET classes.

Comment: Like I said, we don't have a single person on the team who'd ever written a single line of code in C#, we're basically limited to either PHP, Node.js, Python or a combination of the three.